# Reconfiguring Tallit

Tags: tallit-gadol, tallit-katan

If a tallit ceases to become a garment or four corners, and is reconstituted, one needs to re attach the tzitzit.

Does the same a apply when one:

A) Cuts a head hole in the center and wears it like a poncho?

B) Moves the collar to another side?

i.e. are these actions considered like making a new garment?

Comment: I would wonder if a poncho is closer to the original biblical garments than the tallit we use now ritually: https://www.haaretz.com/archaeology/2013-12-26/ty-article/.premium/what-people-in-ancient-israel-really-wore/0000017f-db18-d3a5-af7f-fbbe23220000